# Celery task results not persisted with rpc

Tags: python, celery

I have been trying to get Celery task results to be routed to another process by making results persisted to a queue and another process can pick results from queue. So, have configured Celery as CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'rpc', but still Python function returned value is not persisted to queue.

Not sure if any other configuration or code change required. Please help.

Here is the code example:

celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from celery import Celery

app = Celery('proj',
         broker='amqp://',
         backend='rpc://',
         include=['proj.tasks'])

# Optional configuration, see the application user guide.
app.conf.update(
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'rpc',
    CELERY_RESULT_PERSISTENT = True,
    CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json',
    CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

tasks.py

```
from proj.celery import app

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Running Celery as

```
celery worker --app=proj -l info --pool=eventlet -c 4
```

Comment: how exactly are you checking that the result is not persisted?

Comment: After starting Celery, verified in rabbitmq admin interface - there are no queue bindings to celeryresults channel.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using Pika (Python implementation of the AMQP 0-9-1 protocol - https://pika.readthedocs.org) to post results back to celeryresults channel

Comment: but Pika doesn't resolve the problem that "task results not persisted with rpc", right?

Comment: I mean rpc result backend still doesn't persistent result as expected.