# Celery rpc vs amqp result backend

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, rpc, amqp

How does the rpc result backend differ from the amqp backend? I see in the [changelog](http://celery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/whatsnew-3.1.html#new-rpc-result-backend) that it replaced it, but although it is written as a protocol (with the `://`), the underlying protocol is still amqp, correct?

For instance, `result_backend = 'rpc://'` vs `result_backend = 'amqp://'`. If I use `rpc` as the backend, does it also use SSL when the `broker_use_ssl` flag is set to true?

Comment: celery documentation isn't clear on this. I remember I came across somewhere which talks about using amqp as backend may introduce performance overhead. I can't remember the link anymore. I add a bounty hoping someone with insider knowledge may explain different between rpc and amqp, and how to choose among them.

Answer (score 34):

Consider a scenario, where 4 clients have to queue 100 tasks each.

In case of `amqp` backend, it will create 400 unique queues and stores results in those queues.

In case of `rpc` backend, it will create only 4 queues(1 per client) and stores 100 results in each queue which results in significant improvement in performance as there is no overhead to create queues for each and every task.

For this reason, `amqp` as backend is deprecated and will be completely removed in next release.

`rpc` backend uses the same [publish/consume mechanism of amqp](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/a3c377474ab1109a26de5169066a4fae0d30524b/celery/backends/rpc.py#L198-L215). If you set `broker_use_ssl` to `True`, then it will use SSL.

Comment: Do you mind to further explain what is SSL in celery context? Is it same as "Secure Sockets Layer"? How should we decide whether to enable `broker_use_ssl` or not?

Comment: @CheokYanCheng Yes, it is the same. Whether to enable or not depends on how your client and server are connecting, if the transferring data is confidential or not, or if you need to follow some standards like HIPAA  etc.

Comment: Can you explain if their result persistent behaviors are different. I run into the a similar problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34541282/celery-task-results-not-persisted-with-rpc , where I can't enable result_persistent using rpc.

Comment: @JialinZou Are you getting any error while enabling it? If result_persistent is enabled, it will persist http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-result_persistent

Comment: @ChillarAnand No error, I can enable result_persistent in both amqp and rpc. The difference is that when I use amqp, I can retrieve result in another Python interpreter by AsyncResult(task_id). However using rpc, this only works within the same interpreter. Not sure this is a bug or designed to be. I didn't find answer in Celery documents.

Comment: Are chords going to be supported by the RPC backend? It seemed to lack features, I also had trouble getting back the status of chained tasks with RPC backend.